# node js express4 and passport js lengthy sign in

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport-local, express-4

I am using express 4 with passport js to handle authentication of users.
The front end is Angular JS.

I am basically facing two problems:
1- sign in is lengthy, it takes up to 15 seconds to sign in.
2- once logged in, if i restart the node js server and refresh the page I am back to the signin page even though a cookie is set in the browser.

This is what i have in the backend

```
 passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            user.password = undefined;
             done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: messages['116']});
            }
             user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                 if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: messages['116']});
                }
            });
        });
    }));

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser('a very hard to guess string'));
app.use(session({
        secret: 'a very hard to guess string'
    }
));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The following is the login route:

```
router.post('/signin', function (req, res, next) {
    var result = _.cloneDeep(SwissArmyKnife.resultObjSkel);

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    if (_.isEmpty(username)) {
        result.error.reasons.push(SwissArmyKnife.messages['118']);
    }

    if (_.isEmpty(password)) {
        result.error.reasons.push(SwissArmyKnife.messages['119']);
    }

    if (!_.isEmpty(result.error.reasons)) {
        return res.json(200, result);
    }

    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            req.login(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                 result.result = true;
                return res.json(200, result);
            })
        }
        if (info) {
            result.error.reasons.push(info.message);
            return res.json(200, result);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

when debugging the above code i notice a huge delay when the code reaches

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
```

what could be the problem???
what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing the sign-in page after restarting your server is because you are using the memory store for your sessions. As you've noticed this only has so much usefulness and you should use some persistent store instead (e.g. [redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis)).

Comment: thanks a lot, that makes sense, any idea about the lengthy authentication process????

Comment: Try commenting out if(info) code and check if the overall time gets reduced.